# Move documet to subsite

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api, move, cross-site

I plan to design a workflow that move a document from main site to a subsite. But I found out that REST API moveTo/copyTo method only for within a same site.

Anyone have REST API solution ?
Thank you.

FYI: I using Sharepoint designer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you only can copy/move files between libraries at the same level.
A walk around could by using the endpoint "/openbinarystream" this will retrieve... well a little obvius what this will return. When you get the binarystrem, using "RequestExecutor" you could use a call like this

```
$.getScript(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", function () {
    var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl);
    createitem.executeAsync({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list_template')/RootFolder/Files/add(FileName='file_name.docx', overwrite='false'))",
        method: "POST",
        binaryStringRequestBody: true,
        body: binary, //<-- your binary
        success: fsucc,
        error: ferr,
        state: "Insert"
    });
    function fsucc(data) {
        console.log(data + ' uploaded successfully');
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
    function ferr(data) {
        console.log(fileName + "not uploaded error");
        deferred.reject(data);
    }
});
```

I hope it can help you

Comment: Thank for reply my question. But I just using the sharepoint designer 2013, it does not have coding.

Comment: this is javascript, not C# or servser side code.